# Transferring large file to network drive with unstable connection

Tags: powershell, file-transfer, network-drive

I am trying to transfer a large file (about 10GB) to a drive on the network with an unstable connection (mainly because of it being located very far away). For this purpose I am using PowerShell (to which I am not very familiar with) and the code below:

```
Import-Module BitsTransfer
$Source=”C:\HeavyFile.zip”
$Destination= ”Z:\HeavyFile.zip”
$job = Start-BitsTransfer -Source $Source -Destination $Destination -Asynchronous
while( ($job.JobState.ToString() -eq ‘Transferring’) -or ($job.JobState.ToString() -eq ‘Connecting’) -or ($job.JobState.ToString() -eq ‘TransientError’) )
{
Write-host $Job.JobState.ToString()
$Pro = ($job.BytesTransferred / $job.BytesTotal) * 100
Write-Host $Pro “%”
Sleep 30
}
Write-host $Job.JobState.ToString()
Complete-BitsTransfer -BitsJob $job
```

However, when getting to a `TransientError` the process seems to stop the transfer.

How can I be able to re-try or resume transferring after such error is found?

Alternatively, can I stop it manually and resume it manually from the point in which it previously stopped?

Comment: Take a look at robocopy. No need to make it that complicated if the share is allready mapped.

Comment: Specifically, `robocopy /z` copies files in restartable mode. It also happens to be optimized for exactly the scenario of transferring files across slow/unreliable links.

Comment: Check https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoEazyCopy for RoboCopy GUI